# Gitlab-CI autoscaling using Google Cloud Platform not spawning as expected

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed Gitlab-multirunner following [these instructions](https://verkoyen.eu/blog/2018/08/scaling-gitlab-runner-on-google-cloud-platform), despite of sucessfully installation, still, when I commit the code and CI starts to work, none of docker-machine are spawned out and nothing happens. Docker machine has not been created, and I have no clue what happens. Stuck for days.

Followed [this installation path](https://verkoyen.eu/blog/2018/08/scaling-gitlab-runner-on-google-cloud-platform)

My CI Code:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository - Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end"

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

executeTests:
  stage: test
  tags: 
    - build
    - docker+machine
```

My error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: exit status 1
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: exit status 1
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: exit status 1
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you get any error logs from the gitlab-runner which is doing the autoscaling?

Comment: Hey @rekovni thank you for the effort to answer. Now I am able to create the docker-machine.. but still... : I got this error :  docker-machine ls
NAME                                                    ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
runner-sjv2ybzk-auto-scale-runner-1550249716-26c44db5   -        google                         Unknown   The resource 'projects/projects_customer/zones/us-east1-b/instances/runner-sjv2ybzk-auto-scale-runner-1550249716-26c44db5' was not found ! And we got stuck again. Have u ever seen this before?

Comment: ERROR: Reason: invalid, Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud'. Unexpected resource collection 'projects'

Comment: Not sure why "unexpected resource collection 'projects' has been causing the error!!!! any clue ?